# Laravel8 Model Float function call in controller

Tags: laravel

I created a function in model:

```
public function getGrossTotal(): float
    {
        return $this->amount * 2;
    }
```

I want to use this function in my below controller function:

```
$positions = Position::with(['article'])->get();
```

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) about accessors in laravel.

Comment: I tried by not success, Could you please share example code for controller?

Comment: Please add your attempts and failures in the question.

Comment: positions = Position::withCount('getGrossTotal')->with(['article'])->get()
it's not working.

Comment: `withCount` is for counting relationship [refer to here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models). You need to define an accessor and then count on that accessor (attribute).

Comment: Do you have any example for this?